# OceanData not deep enough or just too deep for me?

Tags: curated-data, geography, entity

It's exciting to see Mathematica/Wolfram Alpha addressing the marine realm in Version 12.2.  Evidently, I was unaware that such data existed since Version 12.0 introduced in 2019.  However, I have two questions that I can't answer.

I copy the example for the Ocean Entity as

```
Entity["Ocean", "YellowSea"]["Dataset"]
```

and then execute.

A nice dataset with all the properties listed in the first column of the dataset.  However, unlike the dataset returned in the example, I get a Missing["RetrievalFailure"] when I try to copy the data into the clipboard. On my Windows 10 64bit machine the data are missing in the second column of the dataset and only a "---" appears where the values in the example are expected to appear.  It seems that some upgrading was done in Vers. 12.2 as there are now 34 properties (rows) rather than the 31 that appear in the documentation. However, actual property values are missing.

Does some other code need to be referenced before Ocean or OceanData can be extracted?

Secondly, does anyone know what the "ACICM491 code" refers to? Both Google and Bing searches don't provide a clue, with the former responding "there don't seem to be many results for your search", while the Bing search returns just two references, both to the Wolfram Mathematica Ocean and OceanData function documentation pages.

References to DIAM6518Code, IHO233Code, and IHO234Code similarly remain mysterious, to me at least.

Comment: The only reference I could find for ACICM491 is to the [Aeronautical Chart and Information Center](https://www.nga.mil/history/1604070546334_Aeronautical_Chart_and_Information_Center.html), a long-obsolete branch of the US Air Force. Not sure if it's the one, but it is plausible. The others remain a mystery. This is an example of an unfortunate trend towards vacuous, self-referential documentation for the more recently added functions in the Wolfram Language.

Comment: Here's where you can find the meaning of the codes: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/appendix/print_appendixe.html They seem to be US gov't id nos. I also get mass failures when trying to get `YellowSea` data, so I'd report to Wolfram

Comment: I think B3m2a1 is right about the source:

Comment: IHO 23-4th: Limits of Oceans and Seas, Special Publication 23, Draft 4th Edition 1986, published by the International Hydrographic Bureau of the International Hydrographic Organization.  ACIC M 49-1: Chart of Limits of Seas and Oceans, revised January 1958, published by the Aeronautical Chart and Information Center (ACIC), United States Air Force.  DIAM 65-18: Geopolitical Data Elements and Related Features, Data Standard No. 4, Defense Intelligence Agency Manual 65-18, December 1994, published by the Defense Intelligence Agency.

Comment: @Stuart I have a suggestion: I can reproduce the part about missing data, but the cause is likely a glitch / a server-side problem. Either way we, the users, cannot fix it, so the question as is might be closed as "requires Wolfram Support". Instead, you brought up a very interesting point about the definition of those acronyms, which was very hard to find. Since the question has received no answers yet, would you consider editing this question or writing a new one to focus on the definition of those acronyms and then self-answering it with the information in the comments?

Comment: B3m2a1 has already hit on the source of Oceans data standards via the the CIA factbook, although the URL for the apparently moved location that I could find is: https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/references/hydrographic-data-codes/, whereas a web search reveals http://www.faqs.org/docs/factbook/appendix/appendix-e.html a top candidate for a previous page.  Some original documents seem available.  IHO 23-4 at: https://iho.int/uploads/user/pubs/standards/s-23/S-23_Ed3_1953_EN.pdf   DIAM 65-18 or perhaps precursor https://earth-info.nga.mil/publications/specs/printed/89009/89009_DCW.pdf

Comment: I have contacted Wolfram in this regard.  It would seem it better to simply get Wolfram to solve the problem and point to the standards they use for curated data.  As you point out, this is a common problem for those using standards.  It's hard to pin them down as they are often altered slightly with the passage of time, the originals get lost in the pile for one reason or another, different audiences use these "prestandards (?)" in different ways.  Documentation of "standards" for curated data needs more attention by Wolfram for those who need to "peek behind the curtains" at times.

Comment: I have been informed from Wolfram that this has been corrected.  It works for me now, although the documentation still has not been updated to reflect the source of the information.

Comment: You may consider adding that as an answer, seems like useful knowledge :)